# Firebase offline ValueEventListener not called from setValue

Tags: android, firebase

I've got a problem with Firebase when my app goes offline.

When I called the setValue the ValueEventListener is not called.

I'm already using the following code:

```
Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setPersistanceEnabled(true);
```

and

```
Firebase myRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
myRef.keepSynced(true);
```